# How to draw text empty inside

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw some text (on a canvas element) with a "shadow" i.e. text empty inside and black around. I'd like to have this black quite "heavy", so I used lineWidth, but I'm obtaining a strange effect as you can see in the image (especially over the M).

How should I proceed?

My code:

```js
 var text = "This is the canvas M";
 var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.font = "24px Arial";
 ctx.lineWidth = 4;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
 ctx.strokeText(text, 5, 30);
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
 ctx.fillText(text, 5, 30);
```

```html
 <canvas id="c"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a problem of `Arial` font ;) Try `Calibri` and the issue will be gone!

the only line I changed from `ctx.font = "24px Arial";` into `ctx.font = "24px Calibri";`

Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zL79sw32/2/).

**UPDATE** (also fix):

Also this will solve the issue with Arial:

```
 var text = "This is the canvas M";
 var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.font = "24px Arial";
 ctx.lineJoin = 'round';     //ADD THIS LINE
 ctx.miterLimit = 2;         //& THIS LINE
 ctx.lineWidth = 4;
 ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
 ctx.strokeText(text, 5, 30);
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
 ctx.fillText(text, 5, 30);
```

Comment: Im sorry but I need to draw the text on a canvas element

Comment: @cdarwin check again please ;) is only an issue of the font, I updated the answer

Comment: In your example i see a bad effect on the v, the drawing of the letter goes below the letter itself

Comment: @cdarwin I found a final solution to it! check one more time or test it on https://jsfiddle.net/zL79sw32/1/ :) is gone even with Arial